# how can i do a responsive grid with unknown height?

Tags: css

I need a grid like this [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XChan.png) but only using css.

I found some libraries but all these libraries use JQ.
How can i do this, without js?

Comment: try Bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: I Do NOT understand your question?? Be more specific about what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Well Don`t know if you are open to use a library.But if you consider it

Bootstrap is a css only library.I does not uses JS and is completely written using CSS media queries for creating grids.

Look at it -[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Otherwise if you want to do it on your own with just css . Dive deep into media queries.

Here are some links that will get you started :

[CSS Media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[W3Schools CSS Media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Also look into Chris coyer - CSS tricks website.It`s has vast collection of CSS magic.For your specific responsive design look into this article:

[CSS Tricks Media queries Snippet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap{background:pink;box-shadow:5px 5px 3px #000; /*animation: bro 10s    infinite;*/width:100%; height:600px;display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-content: stretch;
-ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
overflow:hidden;}
```

Css only
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PPEqJm